# How can I use mutate to create columns named in a vector?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, across

I have a `tibble`, and I want to add columns to it using a character vector. The names of the vector are to be the names of the new columns, and the new columns should be filled with the values of the vector (repeated for each row). This is easy to do with a for loop, but I'm trying to understand how `across` works and I'm having two problems.

```
cv <- c("a"="x", "b"="y", "c"="z")  
tib <- tibble(c1=1:5)
myf <- function(x) { cv[x]}
tib %>% mutate(across(all_of(names(cv))), myf)  ## first problem
#   Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
#   x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#   x Columns `a`, `b`, and `c` don't exist.
tib %>% mutate_at(all_of(names(cv)), myf)
# ℹ Input `..1` is `across(all_of(names(cv)))`.

for (x in names(cv)) { ## do it with a for loop
  tib[[x]] <- myf(x)
}
tib %>% mutate(across(all_of(names(cv)), myf)) ## second problem
```

which produces:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     c1 a     b     c    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 NA    NA    NA   
2     2 NA    NA    NA   
3     3 NA    NA    NA   
4     4 NA    NA    NA   
5     5 NA    NA    NA
```

Replacing the last line with `tib %>% mutate_at(all_of(names(cv)), myf)` produces the same incorrect behavior.

The first problem is that `mutate across` doesn't seem to like making new columns for some reason I can't understand. The second problem is that `across` doesn't know what to do with `myf`. It seems to want some kind of closure that I don't know how to create. (Same with `mutate_at`.) I've looked briefly at `rlang` but can't make heads or tails of how to convert a regular function into the appropriate kind of object.

Comment: `across` is used to loop over already existing columns

Comment: @akrun that explains the error, but it leaves me unsure of whether `mutate` can do this

Comment: @akrun I've updated the question to reflect that `mutate_at` isn't solving either problem

Comment: `mutate_at` is the precursor of `mutate` with `across`. The behavior is to loop over the existing columns.  If you need to create new columns, use a loop or with `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `across` can be used when the columns exist in the dataset and if we want to update those columns or create new columns from that column by specifying the `.names` to change the column name.  Here, one method would be to loop over the names with `map`, create the columns with `transmute` and bind those with original data

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfc(names(cv), ~ tib %>%
                     transmute(!! .x := myf(.x))) %>%
       bind_cols(tib, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#     c1 a     b     c    
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 x     y     z    
#2     2 x     y     z    
#3     3 x     y     z    
#4     4 x     y     z    
#5     5 x     y     z
```

Comment: Could I put this `map_dfc` solution inside a sequence of pipes, e.g. `tib %>% do_stuff %>% map_dfc(...)`?

Comment: @flies Yes, you can do that i.e. `names(cv) %>% map_dfc(~ tib %>% transmute(!! .x := myf(.x))) %>%
       bind_cols(tib, .)`